# Google Developer Console continuously gives errors

Tags: gmail, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-developer-tools, google-developers-console

I am trying to create a project on Developer Console. Step 1, creating the project goes fine. However, I cannot enable an API (Gmail in my case).
I have been trying this continuously for past two hours. I've also tried deleting a project and then creating another project. But I'm stuck.

Creating an OAuth client-ID gives failed to load error.

The Javascript console on Google Chrome lists several 404 Errors from iam.clients6.google.com / clientconfig.clients6.google.com.

Comment: before that enable google + API

Comment: what do you mean by the word "cannot enable an API (Gmail in my case)" Is this the one that you are trying? Developer Console -> API Manager -> Dashboard -> Enable API then go to Gmail API.

Comment: Yeah.. that didn't work. After enabling Gmail API -> Create OAuth2 credentials -> Some error from our side.